# Add quick edit functionnality to plugin table

Tags: plugin-development

Is it possible to add fields to the table listing the plugins of the site accessible to site/wp-admin/plugin.php?

For example, I would like to add an input text field where we could modify the shortcode associated with the plugin.

Or is it possible to add the "quick edit" functionality to this plugin table?

Comment: Yes this is possible. From the top of my head: Query Monitor, The Events Calendar, WooCommerce and YOAST do this, just look at their source for the name of the appropriate hook

Comment: @kero They add links to their plugins page listing that link to Settings pages, but they don't have fields for actually editing anything from plugins.php.

Comment: @ninagath The proper way to do this is to use the [Customiser API](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/) or [Settings API](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/settings-api/) to add the settings for controlling what you need, and then use the method that kero is suggesting to add a link to the Settings page. Adding a field on plugins.php directly isn't really appropriate.

Comment: Okk thanks for your answers, I'm gonna create a link redirecting to a settings' page as _Query Monitor_ does.

Comment: @JacobPeattie afaik they add arbitrary HTML. So it shouldn't be a problem to add your own form or similar (if it makes sense is another topic). I know of at least one premium plugin that adds an input on the plugins page to add your key